10 Pin to 8 pin GPU Power Cable
I have a DL380. I need GPU power cable.
There are 5x GND, 3x 12v outputs on the graphics card. There are 4x GND, 4x 12v, 2x 3.3v outputs on the server.

I connected GNDs to GNDs. I left one free, I connected 3.3v's to GND. I connected 12v's to 12v. I left one free. But not working.
Power comes from the server with 10 pin. 8 pin from the graphics card. How can I connect it properly?

Hi saroman, welcome to Hardware Recs. Which generation DL380 do you have? Also since you said it's "now working", what are you looking for help with?

First of all, thank you very much. This is my first post on this platform of Stackoverflow. There was a typo above, I am very sorry about that. "Not working"

I have HP DL380p

There are 11 generations of the DL380p. Which one do you have?

i trying with gen8

You can't connect 3.3V to GND.  That's shorting the voltage output to ground and may cause the power supply to shut down.  Just connect the 12V and GNDs to the corresponding pins on both sides.

Thank u for your response. I did connect A>1, B>2, C>3, D>Nothing, E>Nothing, F>Nothing, G>5, H>6, I>7, K> 4 and 8. This is successful. But GPU close after 5-6 mins. I think to GPU cant use full power from PSU.

Great, glad you figured that first part out. Second part sounds like a different debugging topic that's better suited for Super User.
